# Windbg: break on timer / scheduler interrupt and print EIP

Tags: windows, windbg, scheduling

Is there a way to setup a breakpoint on the interrupt service routine on Windows which is responsible to trigger thread scheduling and print the EIP of the thread which was interrupted?

I tried to with hal!HalpClockInterrupt but it seems its not the right place. nt!KeUpdateRunTime seams better:

```
Breakpoint 3 hit
nt!KeUpdateRunTime:
805410dc a11cf0dfff      mov     eax,dword ptr ds:[FFDFF01Ch]
kd> !thread
THREAD 82c23bf0  Cid 0320.0474  Teb: 7ffa2000 Win32Thread: 00000000 RUNNING on processor 0
Impersonation token:  e1c1f990 (Level Impersonation)
Owning Process            0       Image:         <Unknown>
Attached Process          82c2dca0       Image:         svchost.exe
Wait Start TickCount      6298           Ticks: 14 (0:00:00:00.218)
Context Switch Count      64             IdealProcessor: 0             
UserTime                  00:00:00.453
KernelTime                00:00:04.312
Win32 Start Address 0x7730a5f7
Start Address 0x7c8106f9
Stack Init f4dc1000 Current f4dc0d34 Base f4dc1000 Limit f4dbe000 Call 0
Priority 8 BasePriority 8 PriorityDecrement 0 DecrementCount 0
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
f4dc0d54 805410ae 00000000 000000d1 0197fb94 nt!KeUpdateRunTime (FPO: [1,1,0])
f4dc0d54 806d2c9e 00000000 000000d1 0197fb94 nt!KeUpdateSystemTime+0x13e (FPO: [0,2] TrapFrame @ f4dc0cdc)
f4dc0d54 805410ae 00000000 000000d1 0197fb94 hal!HalEndSystemInterrupt+0x4e (FPO: [2,2,0])
f4dc0d54 77306f5f 00000000 000000d1 0197fb94 nt!KeUpdateSystemTime+0x13e (FPO: [0,2] TrapFrame @ f4dc0d64)
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
0197fb94 77308dc1 0197fbdc 025c1ec0 03478e70 0x77306f5f
0197fbbc 77309b4a 0197fbdc 00000000 00000001 0x77308dc1
0197ff18 7730a711 02560008 00000000 00000000 0x77309b4a
0197ffb4 7c80b729 00000000 00000000 00000000 0x7730a711
0197ffec 00000000 7730a5f7 00000000 00000000 0x7c80b729
```

Question still is open how to get EIP. Seems Windbg knows how to do it but I would like to understand how. It seems a _KTRAP_FRAME is at _KTHREAD->KernelStack - 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close, but as the current running thread was interrupted by an interrupt, the KTRAP_FRAME (saved registers from the interrupted thread) are put on the stack at that time (when nt!KeUpdateSystemTime() is called).

(Note: live Kernel Debugging on Windows XP SP3 x86).

Reload hal symbols ; see BPs and go:

```
0: kd>.reload /f hal
0: kd> bl
 0 e 805450d0     0001 (0001) nt!KeUpdateSystemTime
 1 e 806e5e54     0001 (0001) hal!HalpClockInterrupt
0: kd> g
```

OK,BP hit at nt!KeUpdateSystemTime:

```
Breakpoint 0 hit
nt!KeUpdateSystemTime:
805450d0 b90000dfff      mov     ecx,0FFDF0000h
```

Let see the stack, include FPO and trap frames:

```
0: kd> kv
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
afb47d64 004482ef badb0d00 01bbb9c4 00000000 nt!KeUpdateSystemTime (FPO: [0,2] TrapFrame @ afb47d64)
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
01f9d814 004483f1 01bb0020 01bbb9c4 000006a2 gfsvc32+0x482ef
01f9d828 004488ef 02c108c0 00081000 000003e8 gfsvc32+0x483f1
01f9d890 0044dc92 000102ee 01f9fd8c 02c108c0 gfsvc32+0x488ef
01f9feac 00437c59 000102ee 00000c90 00000000 gfsvc32+0x4dc92
01f9ffb4 7c80b729 00c9cb40 01e9fffc 00000020 gfsvc32+0x37c59
01f9ffe0 7c80b72f 00000000 00000000 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
01f9ffe4 00000000 00000000 00000000 004a6727 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x3d (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
```

Userland thread was interrupted, trap frame is at 0x**afb47d64**. Let's see the thread:

```
0: kd> !thread
THREAD 8a3702e8  Cid 0c90.0cf8  Teb: 7ffd5000 Win32Thread: e198a360 RUNNING on processor 0
Not impersonating
DeviceMap                 e1f236f0
Owning Process            0       Image:         <Unknown>
Attached Process          89e7fda0       Image:         testk.exe
Wait Start TickCount      21252          Ticks: 2 (0:00:00:00.031)
Context Switch Count      45160          IdealProcessor: 0                 LargeStack
UserTime                  00:00:18.281
KernelTime                00:00:20.125
Win32 Start Address 0x004a6727
Start Address kernel32!BaseThreadStartThunk (0x7c810729)
Stack Init afb48000 Current afb479c4 Base afb48000 Limit afb44000 Call 0
Priority 13 BasePriority 13 PriorityDecrement 0 DecrementCount 16
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
afb47d64 004482ef badb0d00 01bbb9c4 00000000 nt!KeUpdateSystemTime (FPO: [0,2] TrapFrame @ afb47d64)
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
01f9d814 004483f1 01bb0020 01bbb9c4 000006a2 gfsvc32+0x482ef
01f9d828 004488ef 02c108c0 00081000 000003e8 gfsvc32+0x483f1
01f9d890 0044dc92 000102ee 01f9fd8c 02c108c0 gfsvc32+0x488ef
01f9feac 00437c59 000102ee 00000c90 00000000 gfsvc32+0x4dc92
01f9ffb4 7c80b729 00c9cb40 01e9fffc 00000020 gfsvc32+0x37c59
01f9ffe0 7c80b72f 00000000 00000000 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x37 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
01f9ffe4 00000000 00000000 00000000 004a6727 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x3d (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
```

So when the thread is interrupted, hal!HalpClockInterrupt() gets called (see !idt -a for the ISRs) and a trap frame is built. The trap frame pointer is currently in the ebp register:

```
0: kd> r @ebp
ebp=afb47d64
```

So, EBP  = pointer to KTRAP_FRAME = 0x**afb47d64**

A trap frame is like a "context" structure as it keeps all registers from the interrupted thread. Let's see what is the offset of eip:

```
0: kd> dt nt!_ktrap_frame eip
   +0x068 Eip : Uint4B
```

EIP is at offset 0x68 in the KTRAP_FRAME structure. Just apply the offset:

```
0: kd> dd @ebp+0x68 L1
afb47dcc  004482ef
```

The user-land thread was interrupted while at EIP = 0x4482ef. Let's confirm this using the '.trap' command (could have been '.trap afb47d64' rather than using @ebp):

```
0: kd> .trap @ebp
ErrCode = 00000000
eax=00002ba2 ebx=00c9cb40 ecx=01bb0020 edx=01bbb9c4 esi=00c9cb40 edi=01e9fffc
eip=004482ef esp=01f9d814 ebp=01f9d814 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0030  gs=0000             efl=00000202
gfsvc32+0x482ef:
001b:004482ef eb07            jmp     gfsvc32+0x482f8 (004482f8)
```

BTW, you can easily see how the trap frame is constructed in hal!HalpClockInterrupt() by disassembling it:

```
0: kd> u hal!HalpClockInterrupt L0n10
hal!HalpClockInterrupt:
806e5e54 54              push    esp
806e5e55 55              push    ebp
806e5e56 53              push    ebx
806e5e57 56              push    esi
806e5e58 57              push    edi
806e5e59 83ec54          sub     esp,54h
806e5e5c 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
806e5e5e 89442444        mov     dword ptr [esp+44h],eax
806e5e62 894c2440        mov     dword ptr [esp+40h],ecx
806e5e66 8954243c        mov     dword ptr [esp+3Ch],edx
```

See how offsets above correspond to the KTRAP_FRAME member offsets:

```
0: kd> dt nt!_ktrap_frame eax
   +0x044 Eax : Uint4B
0: kd> dt nt!_ktrap_frame ecx
   +0x040 Ecx : Uint4B
0: kd> dt nt!_ktrap_frame edx
   +0x03c Edx : Uint4B
```

Hope it answers your question.

-- **edit** --

As my example was on Win XP SP3, you might have different function names on other Windows system.

Example on Win8.1 (x86). If you can't find the clock interrupt function name, I'd try to check the IDT first:

```
0: kd>idt -a
[...snip...]
6b2ac55a000000d1:   81a237c8 hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt
6b2ac55a000000d2:   81a23aa4 hal!HalpTimerClockIpiRoutine
[...snip...]
```

Only two of the 256 vectors have "clock" in their names (notice that one is for IPI [Inter Processor Interrupt], the other one is the usual clock interrupt).

I'd go for hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt, try to step into this function and see which functions are called later.

It happens you can break on nt!KiUpdateTime or nt!KiUpdateRunTime functions:

```
0: kd> !thread
THREAD 9d0af680  Cid 0bec.0bf0  Teb: 7f8ae000 Win32Thread: 9ce51470 RUNNING on processor 0
Not impersonating
DeviceMap                 a0971118
Owning Process            9d161c40       Image:         calc.exe
Attached Process          N/A            Image:         N/A
Wait Start TickCount      63249          Ticks: 3 (0:00:00:00.046)
Context Switch Count      66956          IdealProcessor: 0             
UserTime                  00:01:12.609
KernelTime                00:00:01.281
Win32 Start Address calc!WinMainCRTStartup (0x003db8d4)
Stack Init ac49bfe0 Current ac49be04 Base ac49c000 Limit ac499000 Call 0
Priority 10 BasePriority 8 UnusualBoost 0 ForegroundBoost 2 IoPriority 2 PagePriority 5
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
ac49bcf4 81ad2ef6 81c63c50 00000002 00000000 nt!KiUpdateRunTime (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
ac49bd40 81bdf7a7 ac49be38 ffd0fc98 00000002 nt!KiUpdateTime+0x23c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
ac49bd90 81a134ae 81a10858 ffffffff ac49beb8 nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x67 (FPO: [0,15,4])
ac49bda0 81a23993 00000002 000000d1 00000000 hal!HalpTimerClockInterruptCommon+0x3e (FPO: [0,0,4])
ac49bda0 81a10858 00000002 000000d1 00000000 hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt+0x1cb (FPO: [0,2] TrapFrame @ ac49be38)
ac49beb8 81a239f3 00000000 ac49bf54 00200006 hal!HalEndSystemInterrupt+0xe8 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
ac49beb8 0041be09 00000000 ac49bf54 00200006 hal!HalpTimerClockInterrupt+0x22b (FPO: [0,2] TrapFrame @ ac49bf54)
0094c978 003c55f2 00000000 00000031 00ad55bc calc!WindowsCodecs_NULL_THUNK_DATA_DLB+0x79
0094c994 003c586b 00aded98 0094c9b8 003c599d calc!CUIController::displayEvent+0x76 (FPO: [1,1,4])
0094c9a0 003c599d 00ad5574 00adeea0 00aded98 calc!CDisplayEvent::deliver+0x1a (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0094c9b8 003d5177 00aded98 5b5012f1 00000000 calc!CEventRegistry::fire+0x28 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
0094c9e4 003d575a 00aded98 00adeea0 03bf38ec calc!CCalculatorState::SetBinaryDigitDisplay+0x75 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
```

(side note: don't pay too much attention on the two trap frames above; it seems the first routine was interrupted as soon as it re-enabled interrupts using the STI instructios, so there are two trap frames rather than just one).

Comment: Btw it seems on Windows 7 it looks different. KeUpdateSystemTime is no longer called from the clock interrupt.